# Spark - nested columns merge

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, nested

I'm working with Scala and Spark 2.1.1. This is a part of schema of my DataFrame:

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- op: string (nullable = true)
|-- before: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- b: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- d: string (nullable = true)
|-- after: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |-- a: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

It describes operations on an external database. In case of update operation the dataframe contains both 'before' and 'after' columns representing row state before and after update operation. 'Before' always contains full row, while 'after' only the updated fields. I need to merge them into a column (and DataFrame eventually) containing the full row after update (simply by taking 'before' and changing values of its fields to the ones taken from 'after', if present). I tried different ways to achieve that (mostly by creating a new column by performing UDF on 'before' and 'after'), but I couldn't accomplish it.

An example with 3 rows (I'll use JSON notation for convenience):

```
{... "before": {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "test", "d": true}, "after": {"b": "3"} ...}
{... "before": {"a": "2", "b": null, "c": "test2", "d": false}, "after": {"c": "test4", "d": true} ...}
{... "before": {"other": "4", "other2": "5"}, "after": {"other": "5"} ...}
```

What I need:

```
{... "fullAfter": {"a": "1", "b": "3", "c": "test", "d": true} ...}
{... "fullAfter": {"a": "2", "b": null, "c": "test4", "d": true} ...}
{... "fullAfter": {"other": "5", "other2": "5"} ...}
```

The problem is the DataFrame contains operations from different tables, so 'before' and 'after' may have different schemas in each row.

I tried doing some operations in UDF by converting 'before' and 'after' to JSON (to_json) and creating a new JSON based on them. Unfortunately to_json method causes fields with null values to disappear and therefore I'm not able to create full row without full, original schema:

```
{... "before": {"a": "2", "b": null, "c": "test2", "d": false}, "after": {"c": "test4", "d": true} ...}
{... "fullAfter": {"a": "2", "c": "test4", "d": true} ...} - "b" is missing
```

Is there any working, simple/efficient way to do it?

Comment: can you post the codes you've tried so far?

Comment: A dataframe should have a fixed schema. Variable schema for each row won't work for whole dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using spark sql to solve the problem.
Lets call your table table_with_updates(id,op,before[a,b,c,d],after[a,c])

```
<!-- language: sql -->
select id, op, struct(
     coalesce(after.a,before.a) as a,
     after.b as b,
     coalesce(after.c,before.c) as c,
     before.d as d) as fullAfter
from table_with_updates
```

obviously you can use coalesce for b and d too but I assumed it is missing from your after schema. Coalesce simply takes the first non null value.

With an UDF you have the issue that it must be typed. You would need case class Before(a:String,b:String,c:String,d:String) and After. Which would not work with null values and require lots of logic and coding. Also even scala udfs are much much slower than spark sql functions.

If you need it more dynamic, what I usually do is just write some code to generate the sql from the column names. Scala is great at this.

```
 val colsAfter = spark.table("table_with_updates").select($"after").columns()
 val colsBefore = spark.table("table_with_updates").select($"before").columns()
    .map(c => if colsAfter.contains(c) s"coalesce(after.$c,before.$c" else s"before.$c as $c")
 val structFields = colsBefore.mkString(",")

 sql(" select id, op, struct($structFields) as fullAfter from table_with_updates")
```